# How can I use DynamoDB Janusgraph Storage Backend using SBT?

Tags: sbt, amazon-dynamodb, titan, janusgraph

I started a Scala project that uses JanusGraph as a library dependency:

`"org.janusgraph" % "janusgraph-core" % "0.1.1",`

The project its currently using the `inmemory` storage backend. However I want to use DynamoDB to persist my graph and eventually deploy the application on AWS.

I found the DynamoDB plugin for JanusGraph https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend and followed the guide to run the Marvel Universe example. However when I try adding the library to my `build.sbt` file:

`"com.amazonaws" % "dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend" % "1.1.0"`

It says that the library was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I released support for JanusGraph 0.1.1 to Central/Sonatype. You can use `"com.amazonaws" % "dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend" % "1.1.0"` to pull in the dependency.

Comment: With using dynamodb-janusgraph dependency in the sbt project, it will run the gremlin-server on the same java/scala application. Is that going to create performance or load issues? would you recommend running it separately and connect using remote methods from java or what is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

If using scala gremlin, this would be the build file

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.1.1",
"org.janusgraph" % "janusgraph-core" % "0.1.1",
"org.janusgraph" % "janusgraph-es" % "0.1.1",
"com.amazonaws" % "dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend" % "1.1.0",
"com.michaelpollmeier" % "gremlin-scala_2.11" % "3.2.5.1",
"com.tinkerpop.blueprints" % "blueprints-core" % "2.6.0",
"org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.0",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
 Resolver.mavenLocal,
 "jitpack" at "https://jitpack.io",
 Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
 Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
)
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross    CrossVersion.full)
```